# Is there a Windows explorer plugn-in for Visual SourceSafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Is there a Windows explorer plugn-in for Visual SourceSafe like we have for TFS Power Tools or TortoiseCVS?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/ess.aspx) is one shell extension for source safe.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with it, but a quick Google search found:

http://www.epocalipse.com/sxp.htm